# how to use select where in as all required inputs

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause, mariadb, where-in

let's say i have a table named tt with ids 1,2

i want to search for all of following 1,2,3
when i use
    `select id from tt where id in (1,2,3)`
i get 1 and 2 for result

but what if i need to show me either all of what i searched for (if exist) or nothing?

thank you in advance

Comment: Use If exists, count(*) ... where id = 1 > 0 and count(*) ... where id = 2 > 0 and count(*) ... where id = 1 > 0 ... then go for select ... else return 'Nothing found' :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try comparing the count that returned to the number of values you compare to like this:

```
select id from tt
where id in (1,2,4,6)
and (select count(distinct id) from tt where id in (1,2,4,6)) = 4
```

Of course for each possiblity you will have to change the query.. for (1,2,3,4,5) you will have to compare it to 5 and etc..

Comment: instead of changing the query for each possibility may be he could load the ids in a  temporary table say "t" and replace the literal list in your query with "select id from t" and the count (say 4) with "select count(1) from t". This would be very practical for large lists.

Comment: Yes he could, and it can save some time , @MahdiAwadi if you want what shire suggested tell me and I'll update my answer

Comment: thank you @sagi it will be great. and thnx shire for the suggestion.

Comment: i can't find better solution for my problem , thank you

Comment: here it is my real query  `select hotel_room_price.id FROM hotel_room_price join hotel_room on hotel_room.id=hotel_room_price.hotel_room_id join hotel on hotel.id=hotel_room.hotel_id where hotel.city_id=2 and hotel_room_price.book_date in (1454878800,1454965200,1455051600) and (select count(distinct book_date) from hotel_room_price where book_date in (1454878800,1454965200,1455051600))=3 and hotel_room_price.last_update>1454484020121`

Comment: There are `DATE` and `DATETIME` datatypes; `1455051600` is sooo un-human-friendly.

Comment: i prefer it because it's easier to use it in php and strtotime, also you can easily change it with from_unixtime ..@RickJames